# Resource files not found from JUnit test cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, resourcebundle

**Summary**

My JUnit tests are not finding the files they require during execution.
I'm using Maven for dependency management and compilation.

**Details**

All files required by the test cases are located in: `src/test/resources`.

For example, `src/test/resources/resourceFile.txt`.

To access a resource I use the following code:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/resourceFile.txt").getFile();
File file = new File(url);
```

But then `file.exists()` returns `false`. And the error I get is:

```
Tests in error: 
  myJUnitTestCase(tests.MyJUnitTestClass): /home/me/workspace/Project%20Name/target/test-classes/resourceFile.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Note, the following gives the same error (notice the removed `/` prefix):

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resourceFile.txt").getFile();
File file = new File(url);
```

It seems as though the files from `src/test/resources` are not getting copied into `target/test-classes`.

Any ideas?

**The following questions did not help**

[Why Can't I access src/test/resources in Junit test run with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613359/why-cant-i-access-src-test-resources-in-junit-test-run-with-maven)

[Loading Properties File In JUnit @BeforeClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983426/loading-properties-file-in-junit-beforeclass)

[How to deal with the test data in Junit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948861/how-to-deal-with-the-test-data-in-junit)

**Software Versions**

Ubuntu 12.04

Apache Maven 2.2.1

Java 1.7.0

Eclipse (Java EE IDE for Web Developers) Indigo Service Release 2

**(truncated) Maven POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>name</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>name</finalName>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: `It seems as though the files from src/test/resources are not getting copied into target/test-classes` Did you actually verify that?

Comment: No, I am an idiot... sorry. I just checked and I can confirm that they ARE actually copied there. Maybe it's due to the "%20" in the path?

Comment: Are you trying to open an input stream from that file?  If so, you may use the following directly to do this (instead of using URL): .class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)

Comment: I'm trying to open it as a File. My solution is now: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.toFile(myClass().getResource("resourceFile.txt"));

Comment: It certainly might be the space (%20) in the path, that can lead to any kinds of trouble ;)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

My mistake, the resource files WERE actually copied to `target/test-classes`. **The problem seemed to be due to spaces in my project name**, e.g. `Project%20Name`.

I'm now loading the file as follows and it works:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.toFile(myClass().getResource("resourceFile.txt")‌​);
```

Or, (taken from [Java: how to get a File from an escaped URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166039/java-how-to-get-a-file-from-an-escaped-url)) this may be better (no dependency on Apache Commons):

```
myClass().getResource("resourceFile.txt")‌​.toURI();
```

Comment: In fact, this question answers that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166039/java-how-to-get-a-file-from-an-escaped-url

Comment: I also saw in this in target file path there was an escape character in complete path (%20), So, I changed the path of my project to a new location without any space. And it started working like a charm.

Basically problem was JUnit was looking for a file in a different location due to escape character and leading to most of the test cases failure.

Comment: Worked with small change>> FileUtils.toFile(myClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resourceFile.txt")‌​);

Comment: can someone clarify what is myClass() means? I need to get a test json into my test class, but TestClass() instead of myClass() seems to be wrong. So, I don't understand how to properly use this line(

Answer (score 13):

You know that Maven is based on the *Convention over Configuration* pardigm? so you shouldn't configure things which are the defaults.

All that stuff represents the default in Maven. So best practice is don't define it it's already done.

```
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. the reason I added it is because I'm quite inexperienced with Maven so I wanted to make things explicit (remove the magic)... but I'll remove the unnecessary configuration in future.

Comment: are you sure the behaviour requested by @AlexAverbuch is really the default in mvn ?

Comment: If you are using Tycho and eclipse-plugin as packaging type, don't forget to aadd src/test/resources in build.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually redundant except in cases where you want to override the defaults. All of these settings are implied defaults.

You can verify that by checking your effective POM using this command

`mvn help:effective-pom`

```
    <finalName>name</finalName>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

For example, if i want to point to a different test resource path or resource path you should use this otherwise you don't.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>/home/josh/desktop/app_resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>/home/josh/desktop/test_resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Main classes should be under src/main/java 
and  
test classes should be under src/test/java 
 
If all in the correct places and still main classes are not accessible then
Right click project => Maven => Update Project 
Hope so this will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The test Resource files(src/test/resources) are loaded to target/test-classes sub folder. So we can use the below code to load the test resource files.

```
String resource = "sample.txt";
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource).getFile());

System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Note :**  Here the sample.txt file should be placed under src/test/resources folder.

For more details refer [options_to_load_test_resources](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-src-test-resources-directory-path)

Answer (score 0):

You may have defined:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

If you did this, the resources won't be present in the target directory when you will launch your tests. And `mvn package` won't create it either.

At the contrary, if you define:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Or nothing as the default value is `jar`. As Maven is based on *Convention over Configuration*. You will end up with:

- src/main/resources => target/classes
- src/test/resources => target/test-classes

Answer (score -2):

Make 'maven.test.skip' as false in pom file, while building project test reource will come under test-classes.

<maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>