# @Value autowire problems

Tags: spring, unit-testing, autowired

I am trying to understand why my autowired @Value("${delimiter}") property is not working. The framework finds the .properties file but does not map the delimiter property.

**Tested.java**

```
public class Tested{

    @Value("${delimiter}")
    protected String delimiter;

}
```

**Tester.java**

> @RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
>   @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/Tester-context.xml"} )
>
> public class Tester{
>
> ```
>  @Value("${delimiter}")   
>  protected String delimiter;
>
>  @Test    
>  public void test() {         
>       fail("Not yet implemented");    
>  }
> ```
>
> }

**src/test/resources/Tester-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:test.properties" />

</beans>
```

**WEB-INF/classes/test.properties**

```
delimiter = |||
```

**Exception message snippet**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.Tester.delimiter; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'delimiter' in string value "${delimiter}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'delimiter' in string value "${delimiter}" ...
```

Comment: You should try to place the `test.properties` file under the test resources `src\test\resources`

Comment: I added a more complete answer to be helpful also to others viewing this question, please accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sounds great, I have now accepted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With maven the resources being used by the tests are the one placed in the `resources` folder, typically `src\test\resources`

In your case move the `test.properties` file to the `src\test\resources` folder.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540457/3224238) to a similar question shows the default maven behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Each **context:property-placeholder** creates a new instance of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - it gets messy easily. You should have one such thing per application and on application level.

P.S.: *@Value has been available since Spring 3.0*