# How to change junit relative resource path for specific maven module?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have the following project structure (both `project` and `module` contain `pom.xml` files):

[image]

Now, in the test class `SomeTest.java` I want to test some functionality using `image.jpg` in the resources folder.

I'm using the following file path as a constant:

```java
private static final String IMG_PATH = "src/test/resources/image.jpg";
```

I then read in this as a file using

```java
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(IMG_PATH));
```

When running this project with the following Maven configuration, everything works fine.

[image]

**However, when running the unit test manually, the image cannot be found, because the file path is different.**

Printing the file path shows the following as an absolute path:

```
C:\Users\Name\Documents\project\src\test\resources\image.jpg
```

As you can see, it's `project/src` and not `project/module/src`.

How can I configure JUnit so that it's root folder for resources is the Maven module folder and not the project folder?

I want to be able to run the tests using Maven as well as by hand for debugging.

Comment: See also [How to deal with the test data in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2948998/165292)

Comment: Do you have a pom file in your module? Does the project has a pom file?

Answer (score 1):

Maven by default copies the (test) resources folder to the `target` folder which it then adds to its class path.

So what works is loading the file as a resource from the class path into a inputstream, and then feeding that input stream into [ImageIO.read(java.io.InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)).

```
try (InputStream inStream = SomeTest.class.getResourceAsStream('/image.jpg')) {
    if (inStream != null) {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inStream);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that the `/` refers to the root of the class path on which the image is found. Also note that you usually should not refer to the `src/` in your code, since at run time only the `target` folder is visible.

Also note that Eclipse (or IntelliJ) when setup properly takes the class path from maven, so this set up should also facilitate running the tests in the IDE for debugging.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. I suspect it has something to do with the configuration settings. I have the following source folders for the java build path: `project/module/src/main/java` and `project/module/src/test/java`. Do you think these are correct?

Comment: All such settings should be standard in maven. Does it work when you run your tests from maven directly?

Comment: If it works in maven but not in Eclipse, this probably means that you did not tell Eclipse that it should view this project as a maven project, and that it should learn all dependencies and settings from the pom file. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399467/add-maven-nature-to-existing-eclipse-project-that-has-pom-but-no-maven-submenu) may help you in properly setting the maven nature in Eclipse.

Comment: I now tried it in IntelliJ and it works haha. Don't know why this is so hard in Eclipse. Thank you for your help!